# full database table update

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I currently have a REST endpoint with basic CRUD operations for a sqlite database.

But my application updates **whole** tables at a time (with a "save" button)

My current idea/solution is to query the data first, compare the data, and update only the "rows" that changed.

The solution is a bit complex because there are several different types of changes that can be done:

1. Add row
2. Remove row
3. Row content changed (similar to content moving up or down)

Is there a simpler solution?

The most simplest solution is a bit dirty. (Delete table, create table and add each row back)

Answer (score 0):

> The solution is a bit complex because there are several different types of changes that can be done:
>
> Add row
> Remove row
> Row content changed (similar to content moving up or down)
>
> Is there a simpler solution?

The simple answer is

## Yes, you are correct.

That is exactly how you do it.

## There is literally no easy way to do this.

Be aware that, for example, Firebase entirely exists to do this.

Firebase is worth billions, is far from perfect, and was created by the smartest minds around. It literally exists to do exactly what you ask.

Again there is literally no easy solution to what you ask!

Some general reading:

One of the handful of decent articles on this:

1. https://www.objc.io/issues/10-syncing-data/data-synchronization/

Secondly you will want to familiarize yourself with Firebase, since, a normal part of computing now is either using baas sync solutions (eg Firebase, usually some noSql solution), or indeed doing it by hand.

2. http://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup/

(I don't especially *recommend* Firebase, but you have to know how to use it in as much as you have to know how to do regex and you have to know how to write sql calls.)

Finally you can't make realistic iOS apps without Core Data,

3. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

By no means does core data solve the problem you describe, but, realistically you will use it while you solve the problem conceptually.

You may enjoy realm,

4. https://realm.io

which again is - precisely - a solution to the problem you describe.  (Which is basically the basic problem in typical modern app development.) As with FBase, even if you don't like it or decide not to go with it on a particular project, one needs to be familiar with it.

Comment: Is there a lib that can maybe synchronize the table to the JSON that is passed in?

Comment: @PrivatMamtora - *that's essentially what Core Data does*.  But it's far from a lib, it's big.  Enjoy!

Comment: Environment is `node`. I was hoping someone made a `package` that can handle it

Comment: We literally build large-scale, realtime, OCC, sync systems - and indeed I prefer Node (on aws with sql) !  there are many hokey libraries around such as this, github.com/3lvis/Sync , but honestly you'll need to familiar with CoreData - just to merely get going.

Comment: GRDB is an excellent library to get in to, and, consider this sort of thing gist.github.com/groue/dcdd3784461747874f41

Comment: for example @PrivatMamtora , here: gist.github.com/groue/dcdd3784461747874f41 at the subheading "Communicating Data Changes to the Table View", is precisely how you do it !